# Json to pandas DataFrame with specific format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

i need to load the contents of a Json file in a certain format in a pandas DataFrame so that i can run pandassql to transform the data.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "bugURL": null,
            "hidden": false,
            "issueName": "Portability Flaw: Locale Dependent Comparison",
            "folderGuid": "223d7f10-3c78-4631-9adf-d60f7762a25d",
            "lastScanId": 1054162,
            "engineType": "SCA",
            "issueStatus": "Unreviewed",
            "friority": "High",
            "analyzer": "Control Flow",
            "primaryLocation": "AdminWSHelper.java",
            "reviewed": null,
            "id": 20114769,
            "suppressed": false,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "engineCategory": "STATIC",
            "projectVersionName": null,
            "removedDate": null,
            "severity": 2.0,
            "_href": "https://fortifyssc.xxx.com/api/v1/projectVersions/23004/issues/20114769",
            "displayEngineType": "SCA",
            "foundDate": "2018-12-13T14:44:28.000+0000",
            "confidence": 5.0,
            "impact": 2.5,
            "primaryRuleGuid": "D8E9ED3B-22EC-4CBA-98C8-7C67F73CCF4C",
            "projectVersionId": 23004,
            "scanStatus": "UPDATED",
            "audited": false,
            "kingdom": "Code Quality",
            "folderId": 288551,
            "revision": 0,
            "likelihood": 1.0,
            "removed": false,
            "issueInstanceId": "FD29B2E76A8C579FC0F7A9ED2BDD4832",
            "hasCorrelatedIssues": false,
            "primaryTag": null,
            "lineNumber": 477,
            "projectName": null,
            "fullFileName": "D:/view_store/AR/CS-SC-TRUNK-HP-FORTIFY/SRN_SC_Common/Source/scx/web/src/main/java/com/xxx/xxx/sc/scx/helper/AdminWSHelper.java"
        },
        {
            "bugURL": null,
            "hidden": false,
            "issueName": "Null Dereference",
            "folderGuid": "223d7f10-3c78-4631-9adf-d60f7762a25d",
            "lastScanId": 1054162,
            "engineType": "SCA",
            "issueStatus": "Unreviewed",
            "friority": "High",
            "analyzer": "Control Flow",
            "primaryLocation": "AdminWSHelper.java",
            "reviewed": null,
            "id": 20114572,
            "suppressed": false,
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "engineCategory": "STATIC",
            "projectVersionName": null,
            "removedDate": null,
            "severity": 3.0,
            "_href": "https://fortifyssc.xxx.com/api/v1/projectVersions/23004/issues/20114572",
            "displayEngineType": "SCA",
            "foundDate": "2018-12-13T14:44:28.000+0000",
            "confidence": 5.0,
            "impact": 3.0,
            "primaryRuleGuid": "B32F92AC-9605-0987-E73B-CCB28279AA24",
            "projectVersionId": 23004,
            "scanStatus": "UPDATED",
            "audited": false,
            "kingdom": "Code Quality",
            "folderId": 288551,
            "revision": 0,
            "likelihood": 0.8,
            "removed": false,
            "issueInstanceId": "71C5977F7D157D875160E5C306ACD805",
            "hasCorrelatedIssues": false,
            "primaryTag": null,
            "lineNumber": 552,
            "projectName": null,
            "fullFileName": "D:/view_store/AR/CS-SC-TRUNK-HP-FORTIFY/SRN_SC_Common/Source/scx/web/src/main/java/com/xxx/xxx/sc/scx/helper/AdminWSHelper.java"
        }]

}
```

I want to get a DataFrame object as mentioned below after parsing the json .

issueName| primaryLocation| issueStatus| foundDate| projectVersionId| fullFileName

Null Dereference| AdminWSHelper.java| xxx| xxx| xxx | 12345| yyyy|...helper/AdminWSHelper.java

Null Dereference| AdminWSHelper.java|xxx| xxx| xxx | 12345| yyyy   |...helper/AdminWSHelper.java

I tried like this :

```
dataSource = FortifyClient.readFileContent('sample.json')    
print('json data : '+dataSource)
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dataSource)
```

Error I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Java_Projects\FortiFyReportingEngine\FortifyClient.py", line 67, in <module>
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dataSource) 
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 258, in json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 258, in <genexpr>
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import json

with open('sample.json') as f:
    d = json.loads(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'])
```